# Python: what's the difference - abs and operator.abs

Tags: python, operators

In python what is the difference between :

`abs(a)` and `operator.abs(a)`

They are the very same and they work alike. If they are the very same then why are two separate functions doing the same stuff are made??

If there is some specific functionality for any one of it - please do explain it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. The documentation even says so:

```
>>> import operator
>>> print(operator.abs.__doc__)
abs(a) -- Same as abs(a).
```

It is implemented as a wrapper just so the documentation can be updated:

```
from builtins import abs as _abs

# ...

def abs(a):
    "Same as abs(a)."
    return _abs(a)
```

(Note, the above Python implementation is only used if the [C module itself](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Modules/_operator.c#l78) can't be loaded).

It is there *purely* to complement the other (mathematical) operators; e.g. if you wanted to do dynamic operator lookups on that module you don't have to special-case `abs()`.

Answer (score 4):

No difference at all. You might wanna use `operator.abs` with functions like `itertools.accumulate`, just like you use `operator.add` for `+`. There is a performance differene though.

For example using **`operator.add` is twice as fast as `+`**(*Beazly*).

Comment: Comparing `abs` with `add` on performance is.. a bit pointless. There is no performance difference between `operator.abs` and `abs`, for example (apart from the attribute lookup on `operator.abs`, which can be avoided with binding to a local name).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Agreed. That's why I used `operator.add` as the example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just wanted to state that things in the `operator` module are not pointless in the face of operators.